# consumer will not know doorbell polarity, which component to auto regulate and stepdown

Tags: power-supply, polarity, step-down

Joe consumer doesn't know or considers polarity of his 2 doorbell wires, which component can a 'simple' device include to self-correct or auto-regulate (sort) for the +- or -+ connection and stepdown 6-36vAC > 5DC   (does such exist? correct terminology?)

Comment: If it's the switch it doesn't matter and if it's the bell I guess that doesn't matter. Now what is the problem you have?

Comment: I expect that many doorbells are AC, so there is no polarity to know.

Comment: @PeterBennett: Not only that, but the particular doorbells he's asking about certainly are (question states `6-36 VAC`).  The confusion appears to stem from mislabeling AC terminals as `+` and `-` instead of `hot` and `common` or `ground`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to vampire some power off of an open doorbell button, the method is to use a full-wave rectifier, filter and then use power supply (switching, most likely) to go from the high voltage DC to low voltage DC without wasting too much power.

You will be limited in power draw by what the doorbell can withstand and not overheat/still operate correctly.

Doorbell transformer are normally 8/10/16/24VAC in North America, but the type of circuit I describe will work for any of those voltages (or for DC, for that matter). Typical doorbell transformers have poor voltage regulation (open circuit voltage is much higher than full load voltage) because they are designed to withstand a short circuit (UL Class 2 'impedance protected', usually).

Lighted doorbell buttons using LEDs work on a similar principle- draw a bit of juice from the AC in series with the doorbell and convert it to DC, but without regulation or filtering.

If you need the power during the time the button is pushed, you'll have to get a bit more clever, either steal some voltage or provide a backup source.

Comment: DC polarity question was ignorance. "6-36 VAC" range is meant to cover international supply. Which small surface Mount Component brand model or 'TYPE' can efficiently step-down 6-36vac to 5dc